# Can't install Clockworkmod Tether offline

Tags: software-installation, android, tethering

I'm trying to install Clockworkmod Tether offline. I wasted four hours doing this and it still didn't work. My problem is:

```
Please compile the included node.js.
```

How do I fix this? And no, I can't install synaptic_0.83.tar.xz either so that's not happening. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the folder where you extracted the files, follow the directions in `node/README.md`. Copied here for clarity, just the parts that apply to Ubuntu:

```
### To build:

Prerequisites:

    * Python 2.6 or 2.7
    * GNU Make 3.81 or newer

Unix/Macintosh:

    ./configure
    make
    make install

### To run the tests:

Unix/Macintosh:

    make test

### To build the documentation:

    make doc

### To read the documentation:

    man doc/node.1
```

You can check Python and Make by running these commands:

```
python --version
make --version
```